# Apache Kafka: upgrade patch

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there a patch file provided by Kafka to upgrade from 0.8.0 to 0.8.1 or it is required to do a fresh install as a part of upgrade?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

From their [documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#upgrade)

> 0.8.1 is fully compatible with 0.8. The upgrade can be done one broker at a time by simply bringing it down, updating the code, and restarting it.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, are the up-gradation steps available anywhere? I mean a step-by-step guide? That should be very helpful

Comment: couldn't find such one, it should be same as a fresh install .. there are few discussion available over internet you might want to look at